# Upgrade to cordova-android 11: Plugin cordova-plugin-local-notification will not work anymore

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build the apk and it throws me the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l6IE.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already solve, with this other:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification-12
```

Answer (score 0):

`compile` has been removed in Gradle 7 and is replaced with `implementation`. The `cordova-plugin-local-notifications` plugin needs to be updated to use `implementation` instead of `compile` in their `localnotification.gradle`.

Someone has already raised an [issue](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1983) on the plugin repo.

But I see you already know all this.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to android studios in the project structure see the dependences and go to local notification plugin and change methot compile with implemententation. Save it and restart

Comment: Question needs editing to include more information.